# Com flexbox, centralizar lista alinhando itens a esquerda

Tags: css, bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Estou usando o Bootstrap 4, conforme documentação (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

Utilizando a classe *justify-content-center* eu tenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: Aplicação da classe Bootstrap, que não me atende]

Minha div está com as classes: *d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center*

Eu gostaria que estes itens menores ficassem centralizados na página, porém, que sua última linha ficasse alinhada a esquerda, desta maneira:

[image: Como eu gostaria que fosse]

É possível? Aceito sugestões de outra maneira para chegar no mesmo resultado, mesmo que não utilize o Flexbox. Preciso que a solução seja "responsiva", podendo servir para qualquer tamanho e quantidade de elementos.

Comment: Não entendi bem sua pergunta.. Você deseja obter o resultado como na segunda imagem, certo? Porém quando abri o seu link do codepen, o resultado foi igual ao da segunda imagem, [veja esse print](http://prntscr.com/ibbsh7)

Comment: Olá @celsomtrindade, acabei atualizando o CodePen após a primeira interação com o usuário dvd. Retornei agora para o código original. De qualquer modo, ele resolveu meu problema usando JavaScript. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que conseguirá isto agrupando as `divs` dentro de uma *div-mãe* e usando os eventos `resize` e `load` (para ajustar no carregamento da página) do jQuery para setar uma largura nesta `div` do tamanho exato até que caibam o máximo de `divs .item` dentro dela.

Não precisa mexer em nada no seu código original, apenas criar uma `div` com um `id` qualquer (coloquei `id="items"`) e agrupar, veja:

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   var content = $(".content.d-flex").width();
   var items = $(".item").outerWidth(true);

   var items_width = Math.floor(content / items);
   
   $("#items").css({
      'max-width':items_width*items+'px'
   });
});
```

```css
.content {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: gray;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="content d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
   <div id="items">
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá dvd, esqueci de mencionar que estou pensando na responsividade, sendo as três colunas somente um exemplo. Com seu código, ele já não funciona diminuindo a tela, resultando em:

[![Coluna com dois itens][1]][1]

[1]: http://i68.tinypic.com/o0huc.jpg

Comment: Não consegui abrir a imagem.

Comment: Sou novo no fórum e não estou sabendo anexá-la ao meu comentário. Segue URL: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/responsivo-jpg Para ver esse resultado, basta redimensionar a tela com o seu código.

Comment: Atualizei o Codepen: https://codepen.io/natodp/pen/EQgogR basta redimensionar a janela de visualização.

Comment: Blz, vou dar uma olhada aqui e te retorno

Comment: Tranquilo, obrigado!

Comment: @natodp Atualizei a resposta. Creio que só vai conseguir via JS. Abs!

Comment: Tranquilo, me atende. Valeu!